# Please rename [arianhrod2e] to [arianhrod-2e]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

A question today created the [arianhrod2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arianhrod2e) tag, which is for Arianhrod 2nd edition. It's missing our conventional dash before the “-2e”, but now that this tag exists I can't create the corrected tag name myself:

[image: “The tag [arianhrod-2e] is too similar to [arianhrod2e]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.”]

Would the diamond mods please rename this tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. The tag is now named [arianrhod-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arianrhod-2e).

Now if someone who's knowledgeable about the game would give it an excerpt (and ideally description) so it doesn't get roomba'd, that'd be lovely (I'm having a hard time finding info about the 2nd ed that isn't in Japanese).

Comment: Thank you! I've added a nominal tag summary. Someone who knew more about it could say more than I did, but it exists.

Comment: Based on my ignorance and googling skills, I think it’s spelled arianrhod.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Ok, think I've fixed that too